# boto3 unknownservice "mturk"

Tags: python, boto3, mechanicalturk

I am trying to use boto3 for Amazon Mechanical Turk. I was trying to get the client using the following code:

```
import boto3
endpoint_url = 'https://mturk-requester.us-east-1.amazonaws.com'
aws_access_key_id = <aws_access_key_id>
aws_secret_access_key = <aws_secret_access_key>
region_name = 'us-east-1'

client = boto3.client('mturk',
    aws_access_key_id = aws_access_key_id,
    aws_secret_access_key = aws_secret_access_key,
    region_name=region_name,
    endpoint_url = endpoint_url
)
```

But I am getting the following error about UnknownService name:

```
botocore.exceptions.UnknownServiceError: Unknown service: 'mturk'. Valid service 
names are: acm,..., xray
```

Why is `'mturk'` not in this list? The code I am using is taken from [mturk developer website](https://requester.mturk.com/developer).

Any suggestion is welcome! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you need to update your version of boto3?

Comment: @dmulter I installed it today. May be the problem is with the new version.

Comment: I just tried a simple version with just the import and client() call along with boto3 1.7.52 and all worked fine.

Comment: @dmulter Interesting. Mine is boto3: 1.4.2-py34_0

Comment: Anyway, moved to python 2.7 env. It works.